# Multi-line SQL query using bcp in batch

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, bcp

I've created a batch file that outputs data from a series of SSMS queries using bcp.

For readability and maintenance, I'd like to set each query as a variable spanning multiple lines, which I'd reference within the bcp call, such as:

```
SET myQuery = 
"select a, b, c, d "
 "from tableA a "
 "inner join tableB b "
 "on a.Id = b.ID "
 "where a.value < .99 "
 "order by a.Id " 


bcp %myQuery% queryout C:\myDir\filenameOut.txt -S ServerName -T -c
```

I'd found the carat operator for doing something similar, and applied as such:

```
SET myQuery = 
"select a, b, c, d " ^
 "from tableA a " ^
 "inner join tableB b " ^
 "on a.Id = b.ID " ^
 "where a.value < .99 " ^
 "order by a.Id "
```

to no avail.  Error message says:

> "[first line contents] is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file."

which makes me think the lines aren't being concatenated properly.

I realize batch files generally don't play well with multi-line operations like this, but is there a straight-forward method for achieving this?

Comment: You need more spaces around the keywords.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, 'keywords' meaning the contents of the SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

```
"select a, b, c, d" ^
 "from tableA a" ^
 "inner join tableB b" ^
 "on a.Id = b.ID" ^
 "where a.value < .99" ^
 "order by a.Id"
```

I would expect this to become.

```
select a, b, c, dfrom tableA ainner join tableB bon a.Id = b.IDwhere a.value < .99order by a.Id
```

See the problems?

This is what you want

```
select a, b, c, d from table A a inner join table B b on a.Id = b.ID where a.value < .99 order by a.Id
```

Comment: adding an extra space before trailing double quote on each line except for last results in the same error.

Comment: @chris I don't think you are prefixing it with bcp -- that error message is from windows not from sql server.

Comment: all of this is being called via a batch file.  When I flatten the query out and remove additional double quotes and carats, it runs fine.  I'm asking if/how I'd be able to create a 'block' query from the single line to make these more readable/maintainable.

Comment: @Chris I don't think this a programming question I think it is an administrative / application question.  Typically batch and shell questions are asked on http://superuser.com/ not here.  As far as I know the only way to use multiple lines is to put it in a separate .sql file and reference the file from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Using a backslash \ appears to work , at least in my tests with SSMS v17.1

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 
'bcp "\
select ''adam'', \
''kev'', \
''bill'', \
" queryout "\\network\path\file.txt" -t"|" -c -T '
```